# Configure header line only if buffer major-mode does not display a header line

Tags: header-line

I've been using code taken mostly from the [header line Emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HeaderLine) to display the file path and current function of the current buffer.

```
(defmacro with-face
    (str &rest properties)
  `(propertize ,str 'face (list ,@properties)))

(defun sl/make-header ()
  "."
  (let* ((sl/full-header (abbreviate-file-name buffer-file-name))
         (sl/header (file-name-directory sl/full-header))
         (sl/drop-str "[...]")
         )
    (if (> (length sl/full-header)
           (window-body-width))
        (if (> (length sl/header)
               (window-body-width))
            (progn
              (concat (with-face sl/drop-str
                                 :background "blue"
                                 :weight 'bold
                                 )
                      (with-face (substring sl/header
                                            (+ (- (length sl/header)
                                                  (window-body-width))
                                               (length sl/drop-str))
                                            (length sl/header))
                                 ;; :background "red"
                                 :weight 'bold
                                 )))
          (concat
           (with-face sl/header
                      ;; :background "red"
                      :foreground "red"
                      :weight 'bold)))
      (concat (if window-system ;; In the terminal the green is hard to read
                  (with-face sl/header
                             ;; :background "green"
                             ;; :foreground "black"
                             :weight 'bold
                             :foreground "#8fb28f"
                             )
                (with-face sl/header
                           ;; :background "green"
                           ;; :foreground "black"
                           :weight 'bold
                           :foreground "blue"
                           ))
              (with-face (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)
                         :weight 'bold
                         ;; :background "red"
                         )))))

(defun sl/display-header ()
  "Create the header string and display it."
  ;; The dark blue in the header for which-func is terrible to read.
  ;; However, in the terminal it's quite nice
  (if window-system
      (custom-set-faces
       '(which-func ((t (:foreground "#8fb28f")))))
    (custom-set-faces
     '(which-func ((t (:foreground "blue"))))))
  ;; Set the header line
  (setq header-line-format

        (list "-"
              '(which-func-mode ("" which-func-format))
              '("" ;; invocation-name
                (:eval (if (buffer-file-name)
                           (concat "[" (sl/make-header) "]")
                         "[%b]")))
              )
        )
  )
;; Call the header line update
(add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook
          'sl/display-header)
```

However, this prevents major modes from setting their own header lines. For instance, when I use GDB with many-windows set to true, this prevents me from toggling between locals/registers and threads/breakpoints.

I tried changing the code block to

```
(if header-line-format
    nil
  (add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook 'sl/display-header))
```

but this does not give the expected result (it seems to check for the first buffer and then not after that).

Is there a way to display my own custom header line only if the current buffer wouldn't display its own?

Comment: Put your test *inside* the function you put on the hook (`sl/display-header`). Have that function do nothing if the test for an existing header line succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drew's comment resolved the issue. I'm posting the correct `sl/display-header` function in case anyone else runs into this.

```
(defun sl/display-header ()
  "Create the header string and display it."
  ;; The dark blue in the header for which-func is terrible to read.
  ;; However, in the terminal it's quite nice
  (if header-line-format
      nil
    (if window-system
        (custom-set-faces
         '(which-func ((t (:foreground "#8fb28f")))))
      (custom-set-faces
       '(which-func ((t (:foreground "blue"))))))
    ;; Set the header line
    (setq header-line-format
          (list "-"
                '(which-func-mode ("" which-func-format))
                '("" ;; invocation-name
                  (:eval (if (buffer-file-name)
                             (concat "[" (sl/make-header) "]")
                           "[%b]")))
                )
          )
    )
  )
```